# GUI doesn't start in VMWare

Tags: gui, virtualization, vmware

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 in a Virtual Machine. It installed correctly but the problem is that the Graphical User Interface (GUI) does not start. I only get the command prompt where I can login.

Any advice how I can get the GUI in VMWare?

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu?  What ISO file did you download?

Comment: I am also finding same problem. I installed Ubuntu on VM ware using ISO and then I am getting command prompt login.
You can use "startx" command to get GUI.
But every time you need to type "startx" command to get GUI.
So I am also searching for solution for this. But this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Once you log in to the command line, check the logs in /var/log. Specifically, check Xorg.0.log, although any recently-updated log might be helpful.